# Python Pandas: Atualizar linhas DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Resumo do problema:**
Boa tarde, estou com uma situação onde possuo dois DataFrames, onde um(df1) possui uma coluna com uma descrição de itens e suas respectivas ID's, e outro DataFrame(df2) com os mesmas Ids, porém com a descrição "atualizada", e gostaria que nesse primeiro(df1) recebesse apenas a coluna com a informação atualizada.

**Problema:**
O primeiro DataFrame(df1) com a descrição.

```
df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Descricao
0   01  Maçã
1   02  Abacaxi
2   03  Banana
3   04  Laranja
4   05  Morango
```

O segundo Dataframe(df2) com as informações "atualizadas".

```
df2 = {"Id": ["02", "03"],"Fruta": ['Abacaxi','Banana']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Descricao
0   02  Abacaxi Maduro
1   03  Banana Madura
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Descricao
0   01  Maçã
1   02  Abacaxi Maduro #Linha atualizada
2   03  Banana Madura #Linha atualizada
3   04  Laranja
4   05  Morango
```

**O que foi tentado:**

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner' , on = ['Item'])
```

Mas não resultou o esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução apresentada por [@Flavio Moraes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/212699/flavio-moraes) funciona adequadamente.

A solução apresentada abaixo utiliza o `merge` como ponto de partida. Segue abaixo para ficar documentado:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)


df2 = {"Id": ["02", "03"],"Fruta": ['Abacaxi Maduro','Banana Madura']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df = df1.merge(df2, on="Id", how="left")
df.Fruta_y.fillna(df.Fruta_x, inplace=True)
df.drop("Fruta_x", inplace=True, axis=1)
df.rename(columns={"Fruta_y": "Fruta"}, inplace=True)
```

O output é:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   Id           Fruta
0  01            Maçã
1  02  Abacaxi Maduro
2  03   Banana Madura
3  04         Laranja
4  05         Morango
```

Answer (score 3):

Você não tem que fazer um merge, mas substituir os valores nos lugares corretos. Veja se esse exemplo não resolve o seu problema:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)


df2 = {"Id": ["02", "03"],"Fruta": ['Abacaxi Maduro','Banana Madura']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df1 = df1.replace ((df1.loc[df1['Id'].isin(df2['Id'])])['Fruta'].values, df2['Fruta'].values)

print(df1)
```

O meu output foi:

```
   Id           Fruta
0  01            Maçã
1  02  Abacaxi Maduro
2  03   Banana Madura
3  04         Laranja
4  05         Morango
```

Comment: Entendi a lógica, funcionou perfeito, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria criar um dicionário e utilizar a função map do pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],
       "Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}

df2 = {"Id": ["02", "03"],
       "Fruta": ['Abacaxi - Atualizado','Banana - Atualizado']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Mapeamos utilizando o id do df1, criamos um dicionário contendo chave e valor correspondente utilizando o df2. Os valores que não tem correspondência no dicionário são preenchidos com a própria coluna fruta do df1.

```
df1['Fruta'] = df1['Id'].map(pd.Series(df2['Fruta'].values, index=df2['Id']).to_dict()).fillna(df1['Fruta'])
```

Saída:

| Id | Fruta |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Maçã |
| 02 | Abacaxi - Atualizado |
| 03 | Banana - Atualizado |
| 04 | Laranja |
| 05 | Morango |